# Enter prints "^M" in the terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line

When I press Enter or Backspace in the terminal, I get this:

```
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): no^M^?^?^?^?^?^?^?^M^?^?
```

What's up with this?

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't happen in every commandline application, yes? Which  program is the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the program that reads the user input can't handle special characters. The terminal is in raw mode. If the program is a script you can use `read -e` to use the Bash `readline` function that can handle special characters.